# Installation python modules

Tags: python

I could not install python module like cv2,  collection.
Everytime  i try to install it show error of 
No matchin distribution found for cv2 
I am using python 3.7.2  and also try with pyhton 3.6.0 and 3.6.5.
.

Answer (score 0):

Operating System ? 
 If you are not able to install it via pip then you try this
1)check ur os version and cpu architecture
2) Go to pypi.org and search module
3) then once you to respective modules page, go to download files in navigation.
4) There you can compatible version and download whl file.
5)then do pip install path_to_dowloaded_whl.whl

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV for python is available in a package called opencv-python.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

The packages are not always named after their imports.

import cv2 doesn't mean the package is called cv2.